# How to use taskflow to parallelize Breadth first search in C++

Tags: c++17

I am trying to use taskflow to parallelize top down Breadth first search. I wanted to ask if this is the right way to do it or there is a better way to do it without storing the parent node.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>
#include <taskflow.hpp>

using namespace std;

void bfs(std::deque<std::pair<int,tf::Task> rtp)
{
    tf::Taskflow taskflow;
    uint depth = 0;

    while(!rtp.empty())
    {
      uint sz = rtp.size();
      for(uint i=0; i<sz; i++)
      {
        int data = (rtp.front()).first;
        tf::Task parTask = (rtp.front()).second;
        std::pair<int,int> p;

        auto taskA = taskflow.emplace([&](){
          p.first = data+1;
          p.second = data+2;
          rtp.pop_front();
        });
        rectp.push_front(std::make_pair(p.first,taskA));
        rectp.push_front(std::make_pair(p.second,taskA));

        if(parTask)
        {
          parTask.precede(taskA);
        }
      }
      ++depth;
    }
    tf::Executor& executor = GetGlobalExecutor();
    executor.run(taskflow).wait();
}

void top(std::deque<int>& rts)
{
   while(!rts.empty())
   {
        std::deque<std::pair<int,tf::Task>> pq;
        pq.push_front(std::make_pair(rts.front(),null));
        bfs(pq);
   }
}

int main()
{
   std::deque<int> rts;
   rects.push_front(1);
   top(rts);
}
```

Thanks

I can only think of doing it this way. Not sure if there is a better way than this.

Comment: What means BFS?

Comment: BFS - Breadth first search